# Is a critical value always a critical point as well?

Tags: calculus, graphing-functions

My impression from reading the definition of critical points is that the function has to be defined there, and its derivative at that value has to be either zero or undefined.

However, in a problem assigned me by my teacher, which is to find the critical points of the function $x(x-4)^3$, his answer says that the function has 2 critical values $x = 1, x = 4$, but only one critical point $(1, -27)$

I think something is wrong here because based on my understanding, if something is a critical value, it is also by definition a critical point.

Answer (score 2):

There is a very small difference between the two.

Critical points are defined only in the domain of the derivative i.e. only when the function is differentiable. So in the case of your function, we find only one critical point, at $x=1$.

But critical values are all those values, where a maxima, minima, or a point of inflection can be found, not necessarily having a zero derivative.

By definition, all critical points are critical values but not all critical values are critical points.

Comment: In my textbook a critical value does not necessarily exist where a point of inflection is found. For instance, in this problem, a critical value does not exist at x = 2 but there is a point of inflection there. Anyways, a critical point can exist only where the tangent is horizontal?

Comment: Also, what about extrema? Can they exist if the derivarive at that value is undefined?

Comment: Why isn't $x=4$ in the domain of the derivative?

Comment: In the book Calculus For Dummies by Mark Ryan, it is stated that any point where the derivative is either zero or undefined is a critical point.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is partly hinted at already in your question. The critical point is a *point* in the plane where you would plot the graph of the function. In general you would write that as the point $(x, f(x))$ or in your case, when $x=1$ and $f(x) = -27$ that is the point $(1,-27)$. The critical value should be the just the $x$ component. So in general when $(x, y)$ is a critical point of $f$ then $x$ is a critical value of $f$.

This function has a different thing at play here. Look at the [plot](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=x%28x-4%29%C2%B3)! At the critical value 4 there is neither a minimum nor a maximum, while at the critical value 1, there is a minimum. I think this is the differentiation your teacher wanted to make. There are two values, and critical points, but only one local minimum/maximum.

Comment: Nope, he literally has said it has only one critical point but two critical values. I guess he must  be wrong then. Also, does a critical point have to be differentiable at the value as the other answer implies ? I think so because in another problem ("|x|"), my teacher says that at 0 a critical value and a local minimum point exist, but he doesnt mention a critical point.

Comment: One important thing to remember is, that there are not really binding definitions in math. Everyone can define everything slightly different. The definition in my head is the same as in Wikipedia: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Critical_point_(mathematics) ... However, your teacher can define a critical value/point however they like. So you maybe have to look up/ask for that definition and they apply that. But you are right. If I were to *guess* what your teacher means, it is that a critical value is x where f'(x) = 0 and a critical point is a min or max of function.

Comment: Yeah I sort of did notice that as I was looking up these definitions and comparing them to those of my teachers and such terminology incongruencies wouldn't be an issue if it weren't for my final exams which is sort of a national test that my teacher has nothing do to with, so I am sort of concerned whether my teacher and the national exam guys agree on the same definitions, I should and will probably ask my teacher but I also feel like I should go with the more standard-seeming definition that in any case where a critical value is found there is also a critical point.